# Error while copiling Java file (Arrays,Nested if statements)

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, compiler-errors

i Have been trying to write a practice piece of code to calculate the fine a library will issue if the book is missing depending on the difference is date months etc... 
Here is the compiler message:

```
Solution.java:26: error: illegal start of expression
         if((givDate[1]-expDate[1])>0){
         ^
Solution.java:25: error: not a statement
   if((givDate[2]-expDate[2]) == 0) (
                                    ^
Solution.java:26: error: ';' expected
         if((givDate[1]-expDate[1])>0){
                                      ^
Solution.java:31: error: 'else' without 'if'
         else{
         ^
Solution.java:37: error: illegal start of expression
    )
    ^
Solution.java:38: error: 'else' without 'if'
     else{
    ^
6 errors
```

And heres the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
 int[] expDate = new int[3] ;
 int[] givDate = new int[3] ;
 for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    givDate[i]=input.nextInt(); 
 }
 for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
    expDate[j]=input.nextInt(); 
 }
 int fine =  testForStuff(givDate,expDate);
System.out.println(fine);

}
public static int testForStuff(int givDate[],int expDate[]){
   int fine=0;
   if((givDate[2]-expDate[2]) == 0) (
         if((givDate[1]-expDate[1])>0){

         fine = 500*(givDate[1]-expDate[1]);

         }
         else{
             fine = 15*(givDate[0]-expDate[0]);

         }


    )
    else{

    fine = 10000;

    }   

 return fine;


 }    


 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using `()` parenthesis where you should be using `{}` curly braces.

```
if((givDate[2]-expDate[2]) == 0) (  // invalid: parenthesis
     if((givDate[1]-expDate[1])>0){

     fine = 500*(givDate[1]-expDate[1]);

     }
     else{
         fine = 15*(givDate[0]-expDate[0]);

     }


) // invalid: parenthesis
```

should be

```
if((givDate[2]-expDate[2]) == 0) { // curly braces
     if((givDate[1]-expDate[1])>0){

     fine = 500*(givDate[1]-expDate[1]);

     }
     else{
         fine = 15*(givDate[0]-expDate[0]);

     }


} // curly braces
```

Comment: See them in line 28 and 37 as indicated in compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

```
Solution.java:25: error: not a statement

if((givDate[2]-expDate[2]) == 0) **(**
```

There is a curved parentesis (maked with **).